# Cannot make a call on this channel because a call to Open() is in progress - WCF

Tags: wcf

I am getting the following error while I invoke WCF service from time to time.  Quick reply would be appreciated

Cannot make a call on this channel because a call to Open() is in progress.

Full exception details

Timestamp: 15/03/2012 2:38:06 AM

Message: HandlingInstanceID: 9727709e-2d51-43d3-b45e-58c105cc3791

### An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred and was caught.

03/15/2012 13:38:06
Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message : Cannot make a call on this channel because a call to Open() is in progress.
Source : mscorlib
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
Stack Trace : 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Choosi.Centrix.UnderwriterWebService.UnderwrittingService.IService.UpdateApplicationDetails(AppStatus appStatus, Nullable`1 ruwStatus, MoreInfoRequired[] moreInfoRequiredList, Int32 uwQuestionSetInstanceId)

regrads,

Raj

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory, but without your code folks will have a hard time giving you any help.